# How do I Include a file in a release package that is not part of the project

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I need to create a release / install package. There is a drop down box in VS that lets me create a release version for the project.  So I hit the publish button and choose the CD option.  Sure enough it publishes the a setup I need. I installed the application everything goes fine though I have no idea where on the target machine where the application ended up???  Trouble is my application has signed XML file that stores the public keys my application uses to enable features depending on what a customer is licensed to do.  I would like the key file to be part of the package that is installed so I don't have to send it seperately.  I have to send the license file but I was hoping to avoid confusion by only requiring the user to only have copy the license file to the local directory.  Which brings up another question were is application installed I did a search and found nothing with my application name????  But thereis an icon onthe star menu and the applicaton seems to run just file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably deployed your application as a "ClickOnce" Application. It installs the program to an obfuscated folder in your users folder. On Windows 7 it winds up in something like "c:\users\username\AppData\Local\Apps\2.0\somefoldername\somefoldername". If you need more control of the installation, the free InstallSheild LE that comes free with VS2010 is not a bad choice. It will let you add additional files as well.

Comment: Many thanks, I looked through the folder and sub folders of my VS2010 but the came up empty hand .  I GREPed around onthe web and came up with the instructions to install here [link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2009/12/14/building-setup-and-deployment-packages-in-vs-2010.aspx).  But after seeing the all the comments about how buggy it made VS and how may folks hate it (they were clamoring for a return to WiX, which I assume does ha same thing) makes me very leery of going this route? Have you used InstallSheild LE with any sucess?

Comment: I have. Though my projects are fairly simple. But still, it gave me no trouble. I also hear that WiX is better, but I found there to be a bigger learning curve for it.